# Angular2 - require module on client side

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, angular2-directives

In the context of a Node.js / Express / Angular2 / typescript (IDE=Visual Studio) app,  I am trying to load a third party .js utility (packery) onto the client side (for use in a directive).  Someone made typescript definitions for it.  The d.ts file looks like:

```
declare module "packery" {
    interface PackeryOptions {  stuff...  }
    class Packery { stuff .... }
    export = Packery;
}
```

I refer to this d.ts file, tell the browser where the .js packery script lives, and then import the module as such:

```
import Packery = require('packery');
```

This compiles without complaint.  However, upon running, the browser attempts (and fails) to find "packery" at http://localhost/packery as opposed to knowing packery is an imported library.  This is in contrast to the other import statements I have made on the client such as:

```
import {Http, HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http';
```

which work - as far as I can tell the only two pieces of information I gave it for those were also a d.ts file and the location of the .js file, just like packery.  But, I must be missing something.  Have tried many combinations of file locations and linking and can't get it to work.  How can I get the proper linking to "packery"?

Thanks!

Comment: as @Langley pointed out below d.ts files are only definition files, they don't contain any actual code from the library themselves.  If you update your question with information on how you're building the app (Webpack/SystemJs/other) we can provide more help with how to load the library

Comment: Thanks.  I understand that d.ts are definitions only.  My question is the following.  This statement both compiles and works:   import {Http, HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http';   if you have the d.ts in your IDE and the proper link in, say, index.html.  The browser does not go to "localhost/angular2/http" to try to fetch the module, it knows somehow the proper location of it.  With packery I also have a d.ts referenced and the proper .js link in index.html.  It compiles but at runtime the require statement causes a load from "localhost/packery".  There must be an additional mapping or link?

Comment: with regards to loaders I haven't messed with the default angular stuff and my understanding is that systemjs is the default (I do load system.js in index.html).  Thanks!

Comment: OK so you need to add a mapping for your .js library in your system js configuration. I don't have an example right now but will try and dig one out

Comment: @Zyzle - this seems to be a step in the right direction.  If I add    map: {packery: 'location of packery js' } to System.config, it no longer attempts to load packery from the server.  However, it does complain as such: "cannot resolve all parameters for class ... make sure they all have valid type or annotations".  It seems to me that if my client side typescript is being transpiled by the client then it would want to know where the d.ts file is in addition to the packery .js file.  I tell my IDE using a /// reference line but do I also need to tell the client (or system.js) somehow?

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround for this and thought I'd post in case it helps anyone, although I am still having difficulty with the setup posed in the original question, that is, getting statements of the type:

```
import foo = require('foo')
```

to run on the CLIENT side.  These work for me in node.js on the server, but on the client, for third party libraries that have been loaded via a script tag, I cannot get it to work, even if I add mapping entries to the system.js config file, irrespective of if I point to a .js file or a d.ts file.

Anyway, what does work is if you load the library using the script tag, then in your IDE put a reference path as such at the top of the CLIENT side code

```
/// <reference path="foo.d.ts" />
```

and ensure that your d.ts file does not declare a module/namespace but rather exports methods etc. directly.  This lets the IDE compile without complaint, and the client side code is able to access the third party library.

However, I'm not sure if it is preferable / best practices to do what I did or if one should be configuring System.js somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Typings are empty definitions of js libraries that aren't written in a typed language. They are only useful in development for IDEs hints and stuff, in your app, you'll still use the library as you normally would, adding the js file in your index.html or w/e you load your js files from.